# Remove all files from Git Remote

Tags: git

I pushed my source to my remote git repository some time ago. Now i want to delete every file on the remote as i want to use the repository for a completely new project.

I tried to force push an empty folder:

```
 git push -f origin
```

But still when i clone it, the files are still there

```
git clone http://scm.mygitlocation/project/repo
```

Comment: possible yes, let me check this

Answer (score 0):

If you do a:

```
git rm -r *
```

And commit & push those changes. The files will be removed from the repository but the files will be available for the revisions.